# What are Forward flight, Straight flight, Level flight, and Cruise flight in a helicopter?

Tags: helicopter

Pretty straightforward: what is the difference between *forward flight*, *straight flight*, *level flight*, and *cruise flight* in helicopters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[Forward flight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicopter_flight_controls#Forward_flight)** is how the helicopter flies in most situations. It flies *similar* to an airplane in this situation, with pitching up and down to increase and decrease airspeed. This is controlled by use of forward and aft cyclic.

**Straight flight** is where the tail rotor is set so that it opposes the turning tendency of the main rotor. This essentially prevents the helicopter from yawing while in flight. This is controlled by using the anti-torque pedals.

**Level flight** is simply when the helicopter is flying at a constant *altitude*. This does not mean, however that its nose is pointed ahead, or that it is flying forward, merely that it is not gaining or losing altitude.

I'm not sure exactly what cruise flight is. When a helicopter is "cruising", it most likely is maintaining altitude and flying straight ahead, but I don't think there is a separate term for it.

Comment: To be pedantic:  Straight also implies in balance since it is possible to have yaw perfectly countered but to be flying anything other than straight. I still have scars on my head from being slapped by my instructor for not having the string in the middle.  Isn't it strange how someone had to point it out when you're learning but with the hours comes that natural feeling of discomfort with flying out of balance. I am guessing that cruise flight refers to the attitude and power setting required for range vs speed vs endurance?

Comment: the problem with this answer is that you can't control a helicopter with any single control. The slightest change in any input (or no input at all!) requires a change in every other input. There are no "tail rotor pedals" in a helicopter. they are called "anti-torque pedals," which corresponds to the yawing tendency you describe.

Comment: @rbp - yes, but adding that qualifier wouldn't add anything to the answer - in such a complex system, I would think it would be understood that changes in one system do affect others

Comment: the "pitch versus power" argument is over, and would have applied even less to helicopters than it ever did to airplanes. http://avweb.com/news/features/Pitch-Or-Power222778-1.html

Answer (score 7):

*Forward flight* in a helicopter means that the the horizontal component of lift is forward of vertical, and no turning component is present. Contrast to *turning flight*.

*Straight flight* is forward flight, with the yaw string centered. Contrast to a *slip* or a *skid*, or *sidways* or *backwards* flight.

*Level flight* means that the helicopter maintains altitude.

*Cruise flight* in a helicopter is the flight regime between departure and approach, at a power setting optimized for traveling between locations.